# Как запустить код сразу со входом на сайт?

Tags: css

Как в css сделать так, чтобы

```css
.a-txt:xxx {
  transition-duration: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

действие началось сразу, со входом на сайт? (Что нужно писать вместо "xxx"?)

Comment: Ничего. Оно сразу применяется к элементу.

Comment: Тогда затухание происходит моментально, текст даже появиться не успевает.

Comment: Почитайте о свойстве, вы его не так используйте. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)